# wrong result after click on price filter first range in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, filter, range, edit, price

I try to edit price filter of magento 1.9. when click on first range of filter it give me wrong result bcz its minimum value is 0.00 I want to change this 0.00 to 1 .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this,

1. You have to maintain the minimum price is Rs.1 for the products.
2. First, Check if any product has price 0 in your admin panel. if has, modify. Then sure you will get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the price filter value with this:

```
<?php 
$getLabel = $_item->getLabel();
if (strpos($getLabel, 'price')!== false) :?>
    <a class="multi-select unselected" href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">

        <?php 
        $getValue = $_item->getValue();
            $fitlerPrices = str_replace('-', ' - ', $getValue);


            $file = basename($fitlerPrices); 

            $parts = explode("-", $file); 
            $getCurency = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
            $priceBefore = $getCurency . number_format($parts[0], 0);
            $priceAfter = $getCurency . number_format($parts[1], 0); ?>
            <?php
                if($i == $count){
                    //item terakhir  
                    echo '<span class="price">' . $priceBefore . 'and Above</span>';
                }elseif($i <= 1){
                    //item pertama  
                    echo '<span class="price">Below ' . $priceAfter . '</span>';
                }else{
                     echo '<span class="price">' . $priceBefore . ' - ' .$priceAfter . '</span>';
                }
            ?>

        </a>
<?php else :?>

    <a class="multi-select unselected" href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?></a>
<?php endif?>
```